# Compress Images in Office with VBA

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, powerpoint

I'm looking for a way to programmatically emulate PowerPoint and Word's behavior of compressing pictures to 150 or 96 dpi (ppi) (and removing crops, if there). I need to make a whole ton of presentations and documents smaller for distribution and can't open them up one by one to change DPI by hand for all of them. Is there any way to do this with VBA?

Answer (score -4):

Not a lot of simple ways to do this, but these techniques can be used: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Office-COM-Add-Ins/32877260/compressing-inlineshapes-in-code.aspx

Comment: Can you find the article you had linked to before?  Also, please post full answers with links for reference.  Thanks.

Comment: I updated the link, sure hope that one holds. Not sure I agree with your statement "please post full answers with links for reference". If I was to simply re-write what was already written, it would be a waste of time. I can understand how you would want that for SO for search engines to find things on SO instead of the original site, but I think that is a little dishonest and unethical.

Comment: As you can see, links tend to rot.  There's nothing dishonest and unethical about summarizing the relevant portion of the post and leaving the link for reference.

Comment: "The page you requested has been removed" Bill the Lizard Owns Stan.

Comment: I think I found a link that works: https://www.office-forums.com/threads/compressing-inlineshapes-in-code.2164020/post-6925019